# How can you make the Docker container use the host machine's '/etc/hosts' file?

Tags: docker

I want to make it so that the Docker container I spin up use the same `/etc/hosts` settings as on the host machine I run from. Is there a way to do this?

I know there is an [`--add-host`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#managing-etc-hosts) option with `docker run`, but that's not exactly what I want because the host machine's `/etc/hosts` file may be different on different machines, so it's not great for me to hardcode exact IP addresses/hosts with `--add-host`.

Comment: I dare to suggest that maybe you rather want to set a DNS of the container to take the host's `/etc/hosts` into account (indirectly). I had the same situation and my solution was to edit `/etc/docker/daemon.json` to point to a simple DNS proxy which reads `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: A little late but ... here they say that /etc/hosts of the deamon will be used: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services unfortunately this is not working in my case ...

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Use `--network=host` in the `docker run` command. This tells Docker to make the container use the host's network stack. You can learn more [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/).

Comment: How would this work on Mac or Windows, which don't have `host` networking?

Comment: A host network is in many cases (stacks, swarms, ...) not an option at all.

Comment: while --network=host will obviously help to resolv this question, everyone who goes with this should be **aware** of other consequence such as a simple exemple, it will map and **open all port mentionned in the Dockerfile to the internet**.

Comment: Emphasizing the comment from @OndraŽižka, "The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server."

Answer (score 31):

Add a standard [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) -

```
docker run -it ubuntu cat /etc/hosts
```

Add a mapping for server 'foo' -

```
docker run -it --add-host foo:10.0.0.3 ubuntu cat /etc/hosts
```

Add mappings for multiple servers

```
docker run -it --add-host foo:10.0.0.3 --add-host bar:10.7.3.21 ubuntu cat /etc/hosts
```

Reference - *[Docker Now Supports Adding Host Mappings](http://jasani.org/2014/11/19/docker-now-supports-adding-host-mappings/)*

Comment: Ref: using `--add-host` option with `docker run`  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#add-entries-to-container-hosts-file---add-host

Comment: Ref: using `extra_hosts` in docker-compose file https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts

Comment: @nakamume link now https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#extra_hosts https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#extra_hosts-1

Answer (score 29):

**`extra_hosts` (in docker-compose.yml)**

https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#extra_hosts

Add hostname mappings. Use the same values as the docker client `--add-host` parameter.

```yaml
extra_hosts:
 - "somehost:162.242.195.82"
 - "otherhost:50.31.209.229"
```

Answer (score 16):

Also you can install dnsmasq to the host machine, by the command:

```
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
```

And then you need to add the file */etc/docker/daemon.json* with content:

```
{
    "dns": ["host_ip_address", "8.8.8.8"],
}
```

Where *host_ip_address* it is the address of your host(localhost for example) on which dnsmasq launched.

After that, you need to restart the Docker service by command `sudo service docker restart`

This option forces to use the host DNS options for every Docker container.
Or you can use it for a single container, and the command-line options are explained by [this link](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services). Also docker-compose options are supported (you can read about it by [this link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#dns)).

Comment: Underrated comment. This is a way better solution.

Comment: Nice. But the Docker part doesn't work for Rancher and Kubernetes.

Comment: Great answer. Just remember to replace "host_ip_address" with the real ip address of your host 

Comment: On Ubuntu see https://askubuntu.com/a/1170073/710474 if port 53 is already in use

Comment: this is a proper solution. using network-mode:hosts is not.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using `docker-compose.yml`, the corresponding property is:

```
services:
  xxx:
    network_mode: "host"
```

[Source](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode)

Answer (score 7):

Add this to your run command:

```
-v /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts
```

Comment: From the outset it looks like this should work, but the Docker container's `/etc/hosts` file is tailored to the container, so replacing the file has consequences.

Comment: It works for me. However when the external `/etc/hosts` is changed, it is not updated automatically inside the container. It needs a restart to update it.

Comment: Yes it's work but it's not a good idea... really risky

Comment: This should work but, I guess it's better if you mount it into some other different file as docker creates its own `hosts` file in each container it creates or, it's included in the image that the container is based on e.g. use this `-v /etc/hosts:/etc/outer-hosts` then, in the init script of the container you can read the contents of `outer-hosts` file then append it to the `hosts` file within the container itself. This way the host's hosts file is untouched while its content is taken into the inner hosts file.

Answer (score 5):

If trusted users start your containers, you could use a shell function to easily "copy" the `/etc/hosts` entries that you need:

```
add_host_opt() { awk "/\\<${1}\\>/ {print \"--add-host $1:\" \$1}" /etc/hosts; }
```

You can then do:

```
docker run $(add_host_opt host.name) ubuntu cat /etc/hosts
```

That way you do not have to hard-code the IP addresses.

Answer (score 2):

The host machine's `/etc/hosts` file can't mount into a container. But you can mount a folder into the container. And you need a dnsmasq container.

1. A new folder on host machine

   ```
    mkdir -p ~/new_hosts/

    ln  /etc/hosts ~/new_hosts/hosts
   ```
2. mount the ~/new_hosts/ into container

   ```
    docker run -it -v ~/new_hosts/:/new_hosts centos /bin/bash
   ```
3. Config dnsmasq use `/new_hosts/hosts` to resolve name.
4. Change your container's DNS server. Use the dnsmasq container's IP address.

If you change the `/etc/hosts` file on the host machine, the dnsmasq container's `/new_hosts/hosts` will change.

I found a problem:

> The file in dnsmasq container `/new_hosts/hosts` can change. But the new hosts can't resolve. Because `dnsmasq` use `inotify` listen change event. When you modify a file on the host machine. The `dnsmasq` can't receive the signal so it doesn't update the configuration. So you may need to write a daemon process to read the `/new_hosts/hosts` file content to another file every time. And change the `dnsmasq` configuration to use the new file.

Comment: You can in fact mount /etc/hosts from the host, moreover, you can mount it read-only: ```-v /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts:ro```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found that it is likely in contrast with the containerization concept! however I solved my problem by adding each *(ip host)* pair from `/etc/hosts` to an **existing running** container in this way:

1. docker stop *your-container-name*
2. systemctl stop docker
3. `vi /var/lib/docker/containers/*your-container-ID*/hostconfig.json`

> find `ExtraHosts` in text and add or replace *null* with
> `"ExtraHosts":["your.domain-name.com":"it.s.ip.addr"]`

4. systemctl start docker
5. docker start *your-container-name*

if you can stop your container and re-run it, you'd have better situation, so just do that. But if you do not want to destroy your containers, just like mine, it would be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a virtual machine for running Docker containers, if there are hosts (VMs, etc.) you want your containers to be aware of, depending on what VM software you are using, you will have to ensure that there are entries on the host machine (hosting the VM) for whatever machines you want the containers to be able to resolve.

This is because the VM and its containers will have the IP address of the host machine (of the VMs) in their *resolv.conf* file.

Answer (score 0):

Or just simply do this:

`docker exec -i <container name/id> sh -c 'cat > /etc/hosts' < /etc/hosts`

Answer (score -2):

IMO, passing `--network=host` option while running Docker is a better option as suggested by `d3ming` over other options as suggested by other answers:

1. Any change in the host's */etc/hosts* file  is immediately available to the container, which is what probably you want if you have such a requirement at the first place.
2. It's probably not a good idea to use the -v option to mount the host's */etc/hosts* filr as any unintended change by the container will spoil the host's configuration.

Comment: As mentioned by Clerenz in a comment on the accepted answer, this is only possible in the rare case that you still have a choice for the used network type.