# Docker and local /etc/hosts records

Tags: docker, hosts

What is best practice to use docker containers with my hosts file?

I have these records:

```
test.devel IP of my machine
test2.devel IP of my machine
...
```

How to do to pass request of test.devel to one docker, and test2.devel to another?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve docker host names (/etc/hosts) in containers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067174/how-to-resolve-docker-host-names-etc-hosts-in-containers)

Comment: I guess you're looking for `--add-host` option of `docker run`.

Comment: And with docker-compose?

Answer (score 0):

Assign Docker ip addresses to your records.