# Docker Cannot assign requested address

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, telnet, xdebug-3

I think I'm pretty close (I hope) to having xdebug running in a docker container, aiming to connect via Visual Studio Code.

I think that maybe I'm supposed to add a config to the `/etc/hosts` file in the container, directing an IP address to the url my files are being served over, but am not sure what that IP address is supposed to correspond to.

The error:

#### via `xdebug_info()` (and in `/tmp/xdebug.log`):

```
[Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
```

#### via `telnet localhost 9003`:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Trying ::1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Cannot assign requested address
```

#### The `xdebug.ini` file:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so

[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.discover_client_host = 0
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.force_error_reporting = 1
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug-local.log
```

#### The `launch.json`:

```
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "xDebug listen",
      "port": 9003,
      "url": "http://mzmbo.test",
      "stopOnEntry": true,
      "pathMappings": {
        "/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/my-wp-plugin": "${workspaceRoot}/my-wp-plugin"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### The `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM "wordpress:${WP_VERSION:-latest}"

RUN apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get install -y \
      libxml2-dev \
      vim \
      lsof \
      ufw \
      telnet \
  && apt-get clean -y \
  && ufw allow 9003 \
  && docker-php-ext-install soap  \
  && docker-php-ext-enable soap \
  && pecl install xdebug \
  && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# Replace php.ini
COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php
COPY docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
```

#### Finally the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  wordpress:
    build: .
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: "myproject.test"
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: "mysql"
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: "wordpress"
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ""
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: "root"
    depends_on:
      - "mysql"
    networks:
      - "front"
      - "back"
    volumes:
      - "wp:/var/www/html:rw"
      - "./my-wp-plugin:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/my-wp-plugin:ro"
```

### Result of `xdebug_info()` shows:

```
Step Debugger   ✔ enabled
xdebug.client_host  localhost
xdebug.client_port  9003
xdebug.start_with_request   yes
```

I bet I need to add a configuration, but not sure what.

## Update

From [this tutorial](https://veselin.dev/blog/xdebug-3-in-docker), I see that `xdebug.discover_client_host=true` "tells Xdebug to attempt to extract the IP of the client from the HTTP request", falling back to `client_host` if that fails. (It checks `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` and `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` variables to find out which IP address to use.) This is the config that replaces xDebug 2's `remote_connect_back`. Most of xDebug's [significant configs have changed](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide) between `v2` and `v3`.

Still getting the same connection errors, though:

```
Trying 192.168.16.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

And in the logs:

```
[21] [Step Debug] WARN: Could not connect to client host discovered \
 through HTTP headers, connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9003. :-|
[21] [Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for 'localhost:9003', \ 
poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).192.168.16.1:9003 (from HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR HTTP header), \
 localhost:9003 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
```

I tried adding an `/etc/hosts` entry pointing `192.168.16.1` to `myproject.test` (in the Docker container) but haven't figured out how to flush the DNS records in the container. Maybe I need to add [extra host mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58994501/2223106) in the container?

Came across a post that suggested [Lando](https://docs.lando.dev), which appears to wrap Docker, can ease some of this pain, but I'm not ready to give up on this yet, so thank you very much if you've read this far.

## Solution (gratefully) accepted below.

I also needed to make a change to the VS Code `launch.json` file:

```
"stopOnEntry": false
```

Because I don't have the WP codebase in my repo, just a specific plugin. With `"stopOnEntry": true`, the xDebug plugin was looking for an (non-existent) `index.php` file (starting point) in the `"${workspaceRoot}`, as opposed to just checking for breakpoints, which is what I required, my local codebase just being *part* of the entire application.

Also, I *think* that the `# comments` in the accepted answer were invalidating the `.ini` file, so watch out for that if it seems like your settings aren't coming up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using Xdebug 3 while some of your configuration parameters are from deprecated Xdebug 2 (`remote_host` and `remote_connect_back` which is conflicting with new `discover_client_host`) - see https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings. Let's start with cleaning up those:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so

[xdebug]
; Set the mode to debug
xdebug.mode=debug
; Trigger the connection on each request/CLI script execution
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
; Do not try to connect to the host reported by HTTP headers, use the one in client_host instead
xdebug.discover_client_host=0
; Force connect to the Docker host IP
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug-local.log
```

These settings should force Xdebug to always connect to your Docker host IP. Depending on your Docker version and environment, you may need to add following setting to your `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
extra_hosts:
  - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

Comment: Fantastic, man. For some reason, though, with those settings, `Development Aids ✔ enabled`, while `Step Debugger ✘ disabled`. `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini` only contains one `xdebug.mode`, set to `debug`, Config file (`/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini`) doesn't have an xdebug entry, and the xdebug ini is in the "additional config files" directory. Weird!

Comment: Indeed, xdebug thinks `xdebug.mode develop`.

Comment: Actually, `docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini` isn't listed in the `xdebug_info()` additional ini files parsed listing, though it's there with the same "root:root" permissions as the ones which are (`soap, imagic, etc`).

Comment: When I remove the `# Set the mode to debug` comment, the `Could not connect to debugging client.` returns. So the error had gone away, because the `ini` file was being ignored. At least it seems that way. Adding `extra_hosts`, as above, doesn't seem to have solved the problem either.

Comment: @MikeiLL indeed, the comments in `ini` files should start with a semicolon `;` instead of `#`. Sorry for that!